# disable external storage on Android device

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

There is a situation when user wants to make possible to lock/disable external storage, in other words make it not mountable until this option enabled after password entered.

For instance when somebody's tablet has been stolen or lost when screen wasn't locked.

Even if data encrypted it will be still observable on the non-locked device, moreover data will appear as decrypted if device screen remains locked and device plugged to pc. PC will recognize external storage with the data decrypted on it.

Is the any way disable external storage programmatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from an application.

Sort of by modifying android itself, but if the device permits you to install your modified version of android someone else can probably install a version without this modification (such as a default version from the manufacturer)

Also if the storage is removable like an SDCARD or even a chip which a good rework facility could transplant, it can be moved to a different reader apparatus lacking this software block.

But if you are okay not permitting access until password or similar authentication has been done (and trust the encryption to be secure), then shouldn't that just be the process for unlocking the encryption?

Comment: Because data is already encrypted (android supports ecryption on the fly) removing SDCARD won't give a chance to read it after. It can be read only if device has not been locked before somebody else took it. But thank you for thoughts. I think without changing firmware there is no way to do it through open API.

Comment: @Maxim - if the data is encrypted to a degree you are willing to rely on, then shouldn't your locking/unlocking process be built around entering/forgetting the encryption key?  Seems like your real problem is balancing convenience vs. security in the lock timeout setting.

Comment: data will be available decrypted if device screen remains locked but device plugged to pc. PC will recognize external storage with the data decrypted on it.

Comment: Only if the android devices remains willing to decrypt the data and retains the knowledge of the key needed to do so.  What I am suggesting is that you think about the timeout at which point that process is blocked.  I'm not sure if current android releases handle this well or not, but generally willfully becoming _incapable_ of accessing the data is better than simply _refusing_ to access it.

Comment: This would be a good solution if android provided some way to manage encryption/protecting features at least a little, like lock device with "encrypted state active" let's say.